# making angular service work properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Following this [reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/3n8m1X?p=preview), I am trying to make a new `service` in angular which serves to show a message on user actions like `add`, `edit`, `update`, `delete`. What I have done currently is,

```
meanApp.factory("flash", function($rootScope) {
  var queue = [], currentMessage = '';

  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    if (queue.length > 0) 
      currentMessage = queue.shift();
    else
      currentMessage = '';
  });

  return {
    set: function(message) {
      queue.push(message);
    },
    get: function(message) {
      return currentMessage;
    }
  };
});
```

This is a part of code which I want to inject in other controller in order to get the message when user do basic `CRUD` in the system. I have `postController` where I am trying to inject this `flash` service like.

```
//considering this example which handles the delete operating
//delete post
meanApp.controller('postDeleteController', function($stateParams, $scope, $http, $location, $state) {
    $http.delete('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(response) {
        $location.path('/blog/list');
        //refresh();
    });
});
```

Now I want to inject that `flash` service in this controller and want to show some message like `post deleted successfully` type of message in bootstrap alert once user delete the post. What else do I need to add in order to get the message to be shown in my view. I am using below code in my common layout to show the `message`

```
 <div class="alert" ng-show="flash.get().length">
            <b>
                Alert!
            </b>
            <br/>
            {{flash.get()}}
        </div>
```

Comment: what is an error??

Comment: I injected `flash` service in my `postDeleteController` but nothing got showed

Comment: Well, I don't see where you store anything in the queue. The set() method is never called in the posted code. Also, the success() method is deprecated for a long time now. Use then(). You also haven't show the code of the controller where flash is injected.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the flash service you have created as..

```
meanApp.controller('postDeleteController', function($stateParams, $scope, $http, $location, $state, flash) {
```

And I am not sure about can you use **flash** in your template file directly..So for this to work another way will be to assign value to a variable in the controller an then use in template as..

```
meanApp.controller('postDeleteController', function($stateParams, $scope, $http, $location, $state, flash) {
$http.delete('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(response) {
    $location.path('/blog/list');
    $scope.value = flash.get();
    //refresh();
});
```

});

And in the template file you can use as..

```
 <div class="alert" ng-show="value.length">
        <b>
            Alert!
        </b>
        <br/>
        {{value}}
    </div>
```